# Awk not working in the second part or sub plot of the gnuplot command

Tags: awk, gnuplot, average

Through gnuplot I am trying to print an average line on the graph, but it is not working, if I use `awk` command in the second part or second sub-plot command like this

```
plot "iops.1.log" using ($1/1000):2 with lines title "job 1",\
     "<awk '{sum += $2} END {print sum/NR}' iops.1.log" with lines title "avg iops"
```

But if I give the value directly that I get if I run the same awk command on the bash command line, the line gets printed like this.

```
plot "iops.1.log" using ($1/1000):2 with lines title "job 1",\
     4590 with lines title "avg iops"
```

The line above prints the running average line in the graph using just one value(4590) in the second subplot

What is exactly happening and why is must not be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bug, but luckily you can calculate the average y value within gnuplot without needing awk:

```
stats "iops.1.log" nooutput
ave=STATS_sum_y/STATS_records
plot "iops.1.log" using ($1/1000):2 with lines title "job 1",\
 ave with lines title "avg iops"
```

Answer (score 1):

When plotting with `plot "<awk ..."` and the `awk`-command returns a single number, you effectively have a *data file* with a single number.
In contrast to this, invoking `plot 4560` plots a *function*, which is then plotted over the full x-range.

If you want to stick with `awk`, or simply as explanation of an alternative, you can do

```
avg = system("<awk '{sum += $2} END {print sum/NR}' iops.1.log")
plot "iops.1.log" using ($1/1000):2 with lines title "job 1",\
     int(avg) with lines title "avg iops"
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct `"<..."` gives a piped file. To calculate and plot the mean, you can use
back tics:

```
plot "iops.1.log" using ($1/1000):2 with lines title "job 1",\
    `awk '{sum += $2} END {print sum/NR}' iops.1.log` with lines title "avg iops"
```